# Cómo crear dos botones de igual tamaño con bootstrap4

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de hacer una página `HTML` , donde simplemente tiene que estar dividida en 2 botones con una imagen cada uno dentro. Lo que sucede es que las imágenes agrandan los botones a un tamaño que excede la pantalla. Lo que quiero es que los botones se acomoden al tamaño de la pantalla y no al revés. Cada botón tiene que estar uno al lado del otro y con un ancho igual respecto al otro.
Si es posible usando bootstrap.

Código hasta ahora(con tamaño hardcodeado):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home!</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'accounts/style.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vota!</h1>

    <div id="main" class="container">
      <button type="button" name="yes">
        <img width="100px" height="100%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Facebook_like_thumb.png">
      </button>
      <button type="button" name="no">
        <img width="100px" height="100%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Not_facebook_dislike_thumbs_down.png">
      </button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Como debería ser, sin agrandar el tamaño de la página(perdón por el mal diseño pero se logra entender):

[image: Página bien hecha]

Comment: Muéstrenos que avance tiene hasta el momento lo cuál está causando problemas. Además `Bootstrap 3` o `Bootstrap 4`?

Comment: @Mati, ya tenés algo de experiencia en el sitio como para saber agregar un [MCVE]

Comment: Es un html básico. Ya borre lo que hice(pego lo que tengo ahora, pero está hardcodeado el tamaño), había intentado con tablas pero no funcionó. Bootstrap 4

Comment: Agregé un ejemplo, lo mejor que pude. Y el código actual.

Comment: ¿Y en el archivo style.css ? tiene algunas reglas ?

Comment: No, ningúna. Está vacio. Quiero usar lo menos posible de css la verdad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien con `bootstrap4` no es necesario el `width` y `height` ya que ya tiene implementado unas clases para esto `h-100` , `w-100` , para que funcione hay que `setear` el `height` al `100%` con `CSS` simple .

La clase contenedora deberá ser `.container-fluid` para que ocupe todo el ancho de la ventana , y lo más importante es los hijos tengan la clase `col-md-6 m-0 p-0` para que ocupen la mitad de contenedor con `margin` y `padding` en 0

```css
html,body {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Vota!</h1>

<div id="main" class="container-fluid h-100">
 <div class="row h-100">
      <button type="button" name="yes" class="col-md-6 m-0 p-0">
        <img class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Facebook_like_thumb.png">
      </button>
      <button type="button" name="no" class="col-md-6 m-0 p-0" >
        <img  class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Not_facebook_dislike_thumbs_down.png">
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial, justo lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez este snippet te pueda ayudar, si es lo que necesitas

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Vota!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%;">
             <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Facebook_like_thumb.png" width="100" />
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%;">
             <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Not_facebook_dislike_thumbs_down.png" width="100" />
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías hacerlo con estilos.

```
<div id="main" class="container" style="display: flex;">
      <button type="button" name="yes" style="width: 100%;">
        <img width="100px" height="100%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Facebook_like_thumb.png">
      </button>
    <button type="button" name="no" style="width: 100%;">
        <img width="100px" height="100%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Not_facebook_dislike_thumbs_down.png">
      </button>
 </div>
```